# Terraform Error creating Topic: googleapi: Error 403: User not authorized to perform this action

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform

**Googleapi: Error 403: User not authorized to perform this action**

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "xxxxxx"
  region      = "us-central1"
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "gke_cluster_upgrade_notifications" {
  name    = "cluster-notifications"
  

  labels = {
    foo = "bar"
  }

  message_storage_policy {
    allowed_persistence_regions = [
      "region",
    ]
  }
}

# create the storage bucket for our scripts
resource "google_storage_bucket" "source_code" {
  name          = "xxxxxx-bucket-lh05111992"
  location      = "us-central1"
  force_destroy = true
}

# zip up function source code
data "archive_file" "function_script_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "./function/"
  output_path = "./function/main.py.zip"
}

# add function source code to storage
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "function_script_zip" {
  name   = "main.py.zip"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.source_code.name
  source = "./function/main.py.zip"
}


resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "gke_cluster_upgrade_notifications" {---
-------
}
```

**The service account has the owner role attached**

Also tried using
1.export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS={{path}}
2.credentials = "${file("credentials.json")}" by place json file in terraform root folder.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the used account is missing some permissions (e.g. `pubsub.topics.create`) to create the Cloud Pub/Sub topic. The **owner** role should be sufficient to create the topic, as it contains the necessary permissions (you can check this [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference)). Therefore, a wrong service account might be set in Terraform.

To address these IAM issues I would suggest:

1. Use the [Policy Troubleshooter](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-access).
2. [Impersonate service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts) and do the API call using CLI with `--verbosity=debug` flag, which will provide helpful information about the missing permissions.